# Ruby RSPEC expect(subject.total).to eq 16 always return 0 when the code returns 16 correctly in pry/irb. Why?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I am trying to make a rspec unit test for the class called Takeaway.
Takeaway has two methods (take_order and total) as well as a list of items with their prices.

- take_order method takes an order list as an input -a hash with keys(item name) and values(order quantity for the food).
- total method uses the list of items with prices and the order list with quantities. and sums up the total price of the items ordered.

The code ("takeaway.rb") itself works in pry/irb, returning the sum.  However, when I run my rspec unit test, it returns 0 instead of the expected sum, and I do not understand why?  Can anyone help on how to expect the culculated sum not the initial value for @sum in rspec? Thank you.

Below are my codes:
takeaway.rb

```
class Takeaway
  attr_reader :order_quantities
  LIST = {"mushy peas" => 2, "kebab" => 4, "fish" => 4, "chips" => 3}

  def take_order(order_quantities)
    @order_quantities = order_quantities
  end

  def total
    @sum = 0
    LIST.each{|food, price| @sum += price.to_i * @order_quantities[food].to_i }
    @sum
  end
end
```

takeaway_spec.rb

```
require 'takeaway'
describe Takeaway do
  let(:takeaway) { described_class.new }
  let(:list) { Takeaway::LIST }
  let(:order_quantities) { {"food1" => 1, "food2" => 1, "food3" => 1, "food4" => 2} }
    describe '#total' do
      it "works out the total price of the dishes ordered" do
        takeaway.take_order(order_quantities)
        expect(takeaway.total).to eq 16
      end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Your rspec `order_quantities` don't match any keys in `Takeaway::LIST`. If there's no price set in `LIST`, why would the total be anything other than 0?

`let(:order_quantities) { {"fish" => 1, "kebab" => 2, "mushy peas" => 2} }`

Comment: Thanks!  Yes, I just realised that too.